# TypeScript 2.6 -> material-ui 1.0.0-beta.24 withStyles with react-router withRouter -> Property 'classes' is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui, typescript2.0

I have been able to use the high order components `withStyles` and `withRouter` together without a problem but upgrading to the latest versions has caused an error.

https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Packages used:

```
"@types/react-router": "^4.0.20",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.3",
"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
```

I have been looking at the tests for both libraries and implementing them one by one is not a problem:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router/test/WithRouter.tsx

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/test/typescript/styles.spec.tsx

However when I try to combine them I get this error:

> TS2322: Type '{ text: "foo"; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick &
>   WithStyles, "text" ...'. Type '{ text: "foo"; }' is
>   not assignable to type 'Pick &
>   WithStyles, "text" | "classes" | "theme">'. Property
>   'classes' is missing in type '{ text: "foo"; }'.

Code, the error occurs only for the line `<DecoratedComponent text="foo" />;`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch, withRouter, RouteComponentProps  } from 'react-router-dom';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import { withStyles, WithStyles, StyleRulesCallback } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { CustomTheme } from 'Features/Client/Styles/MainTheme';
import 'Styles/App.css';
import * as es6ObjectAssign from 'es6-object-assign';
es6ObjectAssign.polyfill();

type withStyleProps = 'mainStyle' | 'innerStyle';

const styles: StyleRulesCallback<withStyleProps> = (theme: CustomTheme) => ({
  mainStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7',
    minHeight: '100vh',
  } as React.CSSProperties,

  innerStyle: {
    padding: theme.spacing.small,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    maxWidth: '90rem',
    margin: '0 auto',
  } as React.CSSProperties,
});

interface IProps {
  text: string;
}

interface IState {

}

class App extends React.Component<IProps & WithStyles<withStyleProps>, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps & WithStyles<withStyleProps>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.mainStyle}>
        <div className={classes.innerStyle}>
          <DecoratedComponent text="foo" />;
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(App);

const DecoratedComponent = withStyles(styles)(withRouter(
  class extends React.Component<IProps & RouteComponentProps<{}> & WithStyles<withStyleProps>> {
    render() {
      const { classes, text } = this.props;
      return <div className={classes.mainStyle}>{text}</div>;
    }
  }
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Solution for component that will use a constructor and does not wan't to copy and paste `IProps2 & RouteComponentProps<IProps> & WithStyles<withStyleProps>`

```
interface IProps2 {
  text: string;
}

type Props2 = IProps2 & RouteComponentProps<{}> & WithStyles<withStyleProps>;

const DecoratedComponent = withRouter(withStyles(styles)(
  class extends React.Component<Props2> {
    render() {
      const { classes, text } = this.props;
      return <div className={classes.mainStyle}>{text}</div>;
    }
  }
));
```

**Original:**

Managed to solve it now by putting `withRouter` first and `withStyles` after.

```
const DecoratedComponent = withRouter(withStyles(styles)(
  class extends React.Component<IProps & RouteComponentProps<IProps> & WithStyles<withStyleProps>> {
    render() {
      const { classes, text } = this.props;
      return <div className={classes.mainStyle}>{text}</div>;
    }
  }
));
```